# Sharepoint 2019 FBA configuration error, cannot open FBA user management settings

Tags: sharepoint, fba, sharepoint-2019

I just configured Forms Based Authentication (FBA) with Visigo solution( https://www.visigo.com/products/sharepoint-fba-pack/) in Sharepoint2019 using this blog ( https://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2016-sharepoint-2019-part-4-adding-users-to-the-membership-database ). But I got error in "Manage Forms Based Authentication Users" with below message in Part4 when I click on FBA user management:

"A Membership Provider has not been configured correctly. Check the web.config settings for this web application."

[Sharepoint 2019 FBA (Form based authentication)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyQ4l.jpg)

I have rechecked my web.config and nothing seems to be wrong.

I did same in sharepoint2016 and it was working as well without any problem.

Anyone has any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the membership provider can’t talk to the database – could be for a variety of reasons. It might be some misconfiguration in the config files. Usually it’s a SQL Server permission issue that causes the problem. You have to make sure that the SharePoint app pool user has DBO permissions on the membership database.